# Jquery click method in second click not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote this codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.nav').hide();

    $('.click#firstnav').click(function(e) {//zeynabiyoun
        $('.nav#firstitem')
            .fadeIn('fast')
            .animate({marginTop:58, marginLeft:672, fontSize:21},'slow', 'swing', false);
        $('.nav, .zeynab, .DL').not('.nav#firstitem').fadeOut('slow').removeAttr('style');
    });
    $('.click#secondnav').click(function(e) {//shobahaat
        $('.nav#seconditem')
            .fadeIn('fast')
            .animate({marginTop:162, marginLeft:712,fontSize:21}, 'slow', 'swing', false);
        $('.nav, .zeynab, .DL').not('.nav#seconditem').fadeOut('slow').removeAttr('style');
    });
    $('.click#thirdnav').click(function(e) {//Download
        $('.nav#thirditem')
            .fadeIn('fast')
            .animate({marginTop:175, marginLeft:825, fontSize:21}, 'slow', 'swing', false);
        $('.nav, .zeynab, .DL').not('.nav#thirditem').fadeOut('slow').removeAttr('style');
    });
    $('.click#fourthnav').click(function(e) {//Khaandanihaa
        $('.nav#fourthItem')
            .fadeIn('fast')
            .animate({marginTop:240, marginLeft:845, fontSize:21}, 'slow', 'swing', false);
        $('.nav, .zeynab, .DL').not('.nav#fourthItem').fadeOut('slow').removeAttr('style');
    });
    $('.click#fifthnav').click(function(e) {//ertebaat baa maa
        $('.nav#fifthItem')
            .fadeIn('fast')
            .animate({marginTop:251, marginLeft:897, fontSize:21}, 'slow', 'swing', false);
        $('.nav, .zeynab, .DL').not('.nav#fifthItem').fadeOut('slow').removeAttr('style');
    });
    //Sub menu Behavior
    $('.anav#yek').click(function(e) {
        $('.zeynab#yek_1')
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .animate({marginTop:135, marginLeft:755,fontSize:21}, 'slow', 'swing', false);
        $('.zeynab#yek_2')
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .animate({marginTop:183, marginLeft:808, fontSize:21}, 'slow', 'swing', false);
        $('.zeynab#yek_3')
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .animate({marginTop:242, marginLeft:842, fontSize:21}, 'slow', 'swing', false);
        $('.zeynab#yek_4')
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .animate({marginTop:235, marginLeft:912, fontSize:21}, 'slow', 'swing', false);
    });
    $('.anav#se').click(function(e) {
        $('.DL#se_1')
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .animate({marginTop:227, marginLeft:856, fontSize:21}, 'slow', 'swing', false);
        $('.DL#se_2')
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .animate({marginTop:236, marginLeft:910, fontSize:21}, 'slow', 'swing', false);
    });
});
```

from this HTML page:

```
<div class="image" id="navigation_image"><!-- Nav Start -->
  <img id="navigation" alt="عکس برای منوی هدایت" src="../images/navigation_picture_transparency.gif" usemap="#mapNum1" />
  <!-- Map For Navigation Picture -->
  <map name="mapNum1" class="map1" id="mapNum1"> 
    <area class="click" id="firstnav" shape="circle" coords="24,30,20" href="#" alt="هیأت زینبیون" />
    <area class="click" id="secondnav" shape="circle" coords="47,100,20" href="#" alt="پاسخ به شبهات" />
    <area class="click" id="thirdnav" shape="circle" coords="112,140,17" href="#" alt="دانلود" />
    <area class="click" id="fourthnav" shape="circle" coords="112,180,16" href="#" alt="خواندنی ها" />
    <area class="click" id="fifthnav" shape="circle" coords="165,190,20" href="#" alt="ارتباط با ما" />
  </map>
  <!-- Map For Navigation Picture -->

  <div class="nav" id="firstitem">
    <a href="#" class="anav" id="yek">هیأت زینبیون</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav" id="seconditem">
    <a href="#" class="anav" id="do">پاسخ به شبهات</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav" id="thirditem">
    <a href="#" class="anav" id="se">دانلود</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav" id="fourthItem">
    <a href="#" class="anav" id="chahar">خواندنی ها</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav" id="fifthItem">
    <a href="#" class="anav" id="panj">ارتباط با ما</a>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Nav End -->

<!-- ُSubNav Start -->
<div class="nav" id="subzeynab1"><!-- Sub Zeynab Start -->
  <a class="anav zeynab" id="yek_1" href="#">از آغاز</a>
</div>
<div class="nav" id="subzeynab2">
  <a class="anav zeynab" id="yek_2" href="#">برنامه ها</a>
</div>
<div class="nav" id="subzeynab3">
  <a class="anav zeynab" id="yek_3" href="#">گالری عکس</a>
</div>
<div class="nav" id="subzeynab4">
  <a class="anav zeynab" id="yek_4" href="#">باقیات</a>
</div>
<!-- Sub Zeynab End -->

<!-- Sub Download Start -->
<div class="nav" id="subdownload1">
  <a class="anav DL" id="se_1" href="#">مولودی</a>
</div>
<div class="nav" id="subdownload2">
  <a class="anav DL" id="se_2" href="#">مداحی</a>
</div>
```

The jQuery click method works for first time but when I click on the fourth menu on the sidemap that named "دانلود" with class `"anav" i="se"` ((دانلود)), this code don't work correct!!!

I wish that the perfect guys could help me...
there is something wrong, because I wrote a similar code for another site and there was same problem...

Comment: replace your selector code to `$('#firstnav')` because `.click` is not parent so you do not need to add `.click` into selector..

Comment: Please replicate your problem in simple jsfiddle example, either you will find the problem or we will have better understanding about your code and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `On` method instead of Click function because when multiple clicks are to be included,it never works,So Change your code as

```
$(document).on( 'click','.anav#se', function (e) {
    $('.DL#se_1').fadeIn('slow').animate({
        marginTop: 227,
        marginLeft: 856,
        fontSize: 21
    }, 'slow', 'swing', false);
    $('.DL#se_2').fadeIn('slow').animate({
        marginTop: 236,
        marginLeft: 910,
        fontSize: 21
    }, 'slow', 'swing', false);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Dear Nanda For Your attention...
I didn't know that...
I'll test it and as the description in the W3school.com, it is better than that way I choose...
Take care...